# LIRC irsend: could not connect to socket irsend: No such file or directory

Tags: pi-2, lirc

I am trying to configure **LIRC** to work with my **Raspberry** and a circuit I build with a transistor and a IR transmitter as explained in this [tutorial](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2015/10/Raspberry-Pi-IR-remote)

After the installation of LIRC, I followed all the steps and I added these two lines in */etc/modules*

```
lirc_dev
lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=36
```

Then I typed this in /etc/lirc/hardware.conf

```
LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"
LOAD_MODULES=true
DRIVER="default"
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_rpi"
LIRCD_CONF=""
LIRCMD_CONF=""
```

After rebooting, I added the configuration of my Samsung remote (BN59-00516A) to */etc/lirc/lircd.conf*

Then I restarted LIRC again but when I run a command to send a IR frequency

```
irsend SEND_ONCE Samsung_BN59-00865A KEY_POWER
```

it complains with the following error:

> irsend: could not connect to socket
>
> irsend: No such file or directory

I am guessing this is a problem with my device socket, because in the hardware.conf file I set

```
DEVICE = "/dev/lirc0"
```

(just because the tutorial states it), but lirc0 file isn't within the folder. 
I couldn't find any other question related to this problem and google didn't help me much either. Does anyone have any hint on this?

Answer (score 2):

You should always check that tutorials are up to date.

You should now be using device tree.

Remove the LIRC entries from `/etc/modules`.

Add the following line to `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.

`dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=16,gpio_in_pin=18`

**NOTE**:  You **MUST** use GPIO numbers not physical pin numbers.  There is no user GPIO36 so I assume you mean pin 36 on the expansion header which is GPIO16.

See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.