# Raspberry Pi 3 lirc "could not connect to socket"

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, lirc

I'm trying to set up my pi as an IR transmitter. I installed the lirc driver as described here.

http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2015/10/Raspberry-Pi-IR-remote

However i made some changes to the modules file on advice from other sources which stated there were changes to how raspbian handled devices. This is touched on here.

[LIRC irsend: could not connect to socket irsend: No such file or directory](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50016/lirc-irsend-could-not-connect-to-socket-irsend-no-such-file-or-directory)

when i enter the command, which should activate the led,

```
 sudo irsend SEND_ONCE SAMSUNG_AA59-00600A_POWER KEY_POWER
```

it returns

```
irsend: could not connect to socket
irsend: No such file or directory
```

I'm using a raspberry pi 3, an IRLED connected from a GPIO pin to ground with a limiting resistor but i intend to use a bjt transistor when they finally arrive from amazon for extra power.

the following line is included in my boot/config.txt file

```
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi
```

my  /etc/lirc/hardware.conf file looks like

```
# /etc/lirc/hardware.conf
#
# Arguments which will be used when launching lircd
LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"

#Don't start lircmd even if there seems to be a good config file
#START_LIRCMD=false

#Don't start irexec, even if a good config file seems to exist.
#START_IREXEC=false

#Try to load appropriate kernel modules
LOAD_MODULES=true

# Run "lircd --driver=help" for a list of supported drivers.
DRIVER="default"
# usually /dev/lirc0 is the correct setting for systems using udev
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_rpi"

# Default configuration files for your hardware if any
LIRCD_CONF=""
LIRCMD_CONF=""
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

the services lirc reads the data which come from the driver of your ir receiver and transforms it into a VALUE (depending on your lircd.conf) and write it on a SOCKET which is located at /var/run/lirc/lircd by default.

Then the value written in the socket is transformed to a string interpreted by an an lirc client (an application), the configuration file for this last step is ~/.lircrc

For this chain to be active, you must start the lirc service and... the socket !
you can do it by typing :

```
lircd
```

in your prompt. It will creates a socket at the default location mentioned above otherwise you can set the location of the socket by :

```
lircd -o <socket_file>
```

Comment: Thanks, that got lirc running, embarrassed i didnt know to do that. im getting a different error now when i try to use irsend. It tells me "hardware does not support sending". I assume this has got something to do with the /etc/lirc/hardware.conf file but i have the default file and im not sure what to change